# Want to fetch data from RESTAPI of the particular person who has logged in

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a beginner in Angular. I have some data stored in an REST API which returns JSON data which I am fetching without any challenge. But now I have created a login page where I am entering only username. The thing I want is to fetch the data of the person who has logged in through that login page and ignore other data

Email I am storing in a variable. But the challenge I am facing here is I don't know how to handle HTTPCLIENT to provide me the data of particular email.

dataservice.Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Configuration } from "./app.constants";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { userdata } from "./tables/data";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/observable/throw";




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataserviceService {

  private _actionUrl:any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private configuration:Configuration) {
    this._actionUrl=configuration.serverWithApiUrl;
   }

   public getAll(email: any): Observable<userdata[]> {
     return this.http.get<userdata[]>(this._actionUrl,).catch(this.errorHandler);

}

errorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse){
return Observable.throw(error.message ||"Server Error")
}
}
```

Tables.Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.service.getAll(this.email).subscribe(data => this.headerRow = data,
      error => this.errorMsg = error);
    this.service.getAll(this.email).subscribe(data1 => this.dataRows = data1,
      error => this.errorMsg = error);
}
```

Tables.component.html

```
table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th *ngFor="let daata of headerRow">
                           {{daata.id}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>

                      <td *ngFor="let daata of dataRows">
                        {{daata.id}}
                        {{daata.phone}} 
                        {{daata.role}} 
                        {{daata.email}} 
                        {{daata.city}} 
                        {{daata.firstName}}
                        {{daata.lastName}}
                      </td>

                      <td><i class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#content"></i></td>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-history" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update"></i></td>

                    </tr>


                  </tbody>
                  <br>

                </table>
```

data.ts(interface)

```
export interface userdata{
    id: Number,
    phone: Number,
    email:any,
    city:string,
    role:string,
    firstName:string,
    lastName:string
}
```

Comment: Do you have a feature from the backend to fetch data for a specific filter

Comment: can you show any example? @AmmarHussain

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create a BehaviorSubject in the service class. Which will have a latest value.

```
private dataBSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    public latestData = this.dataBSubject.asObservable();

    public getAll(email: any): Observable<userdata[]> {
         return this.http.get<userdata[]>(this._actionUrl,).pipe(
         tap((reponse)=> this.dataBSubject.next(response));
         ).catch(this.errorHandler);


         getEmail(){
           return this.latestData pipe(map(data=> {
           return data.email;
           }));
         }
    }
```

Now subscribe in your getEmail() observeable

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use credentials for this. Once you are authenticated you should not send the email of the person who has logged in at all, think that if you do so anyone who knows your email could access your data by just sending the right request to the API. You could create a token for example and manage the credentials at the API end, so this API only sends information based on privileges. This way you simplify communication and you also avoid information leakage.

Comment: This is dummy. My actual one have credentials @Abdel Rodriguez